# Unit testing using Jasmine: Unable to query input element in Shadow DOM of Polymer 2 component inside Angular page

Tags: angular, jasmine, css-selectors, polymer

I am working with some Polymer 2 components which implement ShadowDOM v1 spec and I need to select elements (e.g. input) inside their shadowRoots to run unit tests and few integration tests using Jasmine.

Expected Behavior:

We should be able to access Shadow DOM elements using Jasmine selectors.

var allInputs = fixture.debugElement.queryAll(By.css('input')); // does not give the input elements inside shadow DOM.

[image]

```
import { TestBed, ComponentFixture, async } from '@angular/core/testing';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';

import { NgModule, CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA, NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA} from '@angular/core';

import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';

import { By } from '@angular/platform-browser';

describe('AppComponent', () => 
{


let component: AppComponent;

let fixture: ComponentFixture<AppComponent>;



beforeEach(async(() => 
{

    TestBed.configureTestingModule({

        declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],

        imports: [
    FormsModule
  ],

        schemas: [CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA]
}).compileComponents();

    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(AppComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;

}));

  it('should have default value set for first name and last name', () => 
  {
    fixture.detectChanges();
    var allInputs =  fixture.debugElement.queryAll(By.css('input'));
    var firstNameInput = allInputs[0].nativeElement; // Unable to retrieve the input element from the polymer web component.

    var lastNameInput = allInputs[1].nativeElement; // Unable to retrieve the input element from the polymer web component.
    expect(firstNameInput.value).toBe('');
    expect(lastNameInput.value).toBe('');

  });
});
```

What is the best way I can test the Polymer Web Components inside Angular page?
Or whether we have a mechanism to mock web components while unit testing Angular component?

My environment:

Angular CLI: 1.6.4
Node: 6.10.0
Angular: 5.2.0

"devDependencies": {
"karma-jasmine": "^0.3.6",
"jasmine": "^2.4.1",
"jasmine-core": "^2.2.0"
}